# Org babel - return results of multiple statements

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

This must be very simple, but I haven't been able to find an answer.
How can I have org-babel output the results of multiple statements?

Ex.:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC scheme :exports both
(define square (lambda (x) (* x x)))
(define (smallest-divisor n)
  (define (divides? a b)
    (= (remainder b a) 0))
  (define (find-divisor n test-divisor)
    (cond ((> (square test-divisor) n) n)
          ((divides? test-divisor n) test-divisor)
          (else (find-divisor n (+ test-divisor 1)))))
  (find-divisor n 2))

;; 3 statements follow:
(smallest-divisor 199)
(smallest-divisor 1999)
(smallest-divisor 19999)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
7
```

I'd like results to give me all values, as in:

```
#+RESULTS:
199
1999
7
```

Please point me to an answer, should this question happen to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice thing about org babel is that it has some understanding about the data types for the languages it supports. The solution is to have your scheme code return a list. This seems to work for me:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC scheme :results list
(define square (lambda (x) (* x x)))
(define (smallest-divisor n)
  (define (divides? a b)
    (= (remainder b a) 0))
  (define (find-divisor n test-divisor)
    (cond ((> (square test-divisor) n) n)
          ((divides? test-divisor n) test-divisor)
          (else (find-divisor n (+ test-divisor 1)))))
  (find-divisor n 2))

;; 3 statements follow:
(list
  (smallest-divisor 199)
  (smallest-divisor 1999)
  (smallest-divisor 19999))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
- 199
- 1999
- 7
```

Comment: Cool, awesome workaround.

Comment: This is not a workaround, this is how it's designed to work. Org-babel's understanding of data types is limited to lists and matrices, or 1- to 2-dimensional arrays. This makes it possible to create something similar to unix pipelines for tabular data.